# Obtaining a winner from a table using a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, voting

I have created a voting application in Borlands Delphi 7 that registers votes and updates an access table
My access table consists of two columns, column 1 is the candidate's name, and column 2 is the number of votes he/she has obtained

**What would the SQL statement be if I wanted to obtain the candidate(s) with the most votes?**

I have tried

```
SELECT Max(Candidate.[Candidate Name]) AS [MaxOfCandidate Name], Max(Candidate.[Number of  Votes]) AS [MaxOfNumber of  Votes]
FROM Candidate

;
```

But this one returns one value and therefore if there are 2 or more candidates with the same amount of votes only the first name will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dmax` expression to determine the highest vote count.  And use that value to retrieve rows matching that count.

```sql
SELECT [Candidate Name], [Number of  Votes]
FROM Candidate
WHERE [Number of  Votes] = DMax("[Number of  Votes]", "Candidate");
```

However `DMax` is Access-specific.  Since you're using Delphi, perhaps you would prefer a more portable query.  If so, you can use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause to get the maximum vote count.

```sql
SELECT [Candidate Name], [Number of  Votes]
FROM Candidate
WHERE
    [Number of  Votes] = 
        (
            SELECT Max([Number of  Votes])
            FROM Candidate
        );
```

Comment: Thank you so much HansUp. Really helped, i never knew you could have something like a sub query